# Trouble with Generics in Java

Tags: java, generics, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am using RestAssured framework for api calls and I want to create a method that will return give me value from the JSON response in the specific variable type.
I want to use generic return type but I don't like me implementation.
The RestAssured getList() returns a list of values according to JSON path and cast to value type.
When I implement the getList() method, I have to cast the result to T in order to comply to the return value type:

```
public <T> T getValuesFromResponse(Response response, ValueTypeEnum value) {
    T t = null;
    switch (value) {
        case ID:
            //Will return List<Integer>
            t = (T) response.thenReturn().jsonPath().getList("data.id", Integer.class);
            break;
        case NAME:
            //Will return List<String>
            t = (T) response.thenReturn().jsonPath().getList("data.name", String.class);
            break;
    }
    return t;
}
```

When I want to call this method, I have to cast the values again to the type I need, i.e:

```
((List<Integer>) getValuesFromResponse(response, ValueTypeEnum.ID)).get(0)
```

**How do I avoid the double casting?

Is my implementation correct for using generic `List<T>` return type?**

Comment: I tried that, but it does not compile.   
```public <T> List<T> getValuesFromResponse(Response response, DeviceValues value) {
return response.thenReturn().jsonPath().getList("data.id", Integer.class);
}
```
the error is:
Incompatible equality constraint: T and Integer

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about using a method like this:

```
 public <T> List<T> getValuesFromResponse(Response response, String key, Class <T> clazz) {
    return response.thenReturn().jsonPath().getList(key, clazz);
}
```

... and then call it as:

```
List<Integer> listOfIds = getValuesFromResponse (response, "data.id", Integer.class);
List<String> listOfNames = getValuesFromResponse (response, "data.name", String.class);
```

I have't tried it to compile with the real 'Response' class, but I think this should work. Please let me know.

Comment: This works, but it requires the "user" to define the return class type, while i wanted it to be more generic.   strange that if i use "clazz" that is defined as Integer.class it compiles, but if i use straight Integer.class, it wont

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to have a method that returns a list of objects of particular class to avoid typecast. And want only to pass ValueTypeEnum. This enumeration value represents: (1) what is the name of the field in the response like:'data.name' and (2) what is the type (class of the objects) that the list will contain, like: 'String'. Identifying values of the ValueTypeEnum means it is a runtime processing, while avoiding type cast means we know compile time what class is returned in particular scenario. I am not sure those two are possible at the same time. Good luck.